# Synchronizer for importing XML files into a database when folder content changes

Tags: c#, object-oriented, database, xml, factory-method

I have created a Synchronizer, the purpose of which is to read data from an XML source file and store the result in a DB.

I have different source types, for example Student.XML, School.XML, etc. These files are copied in my source directory, C:\Source.

My Synchronizer watches the Source folder, and every time there is a new file, it should read it, map it to my domain class and write the domain class into the DB.

If C:\Source folder contains Student.XML, it should read the content of the XML file and copy it in `Student` `Table` in the DB. If C:\Source contains School.XML, it should read the file and copy the content to `School` `Table`.

To solve this, I have defined an `ISyncer` interface:

```
public interface ISyncer
{
    // Read input and synchronize destination, return error message if any
    string Sync();
}
```

Now all my Syncer types (e.g. StudentSyncer, SchoolSyncer, etc) should implement this interface:

```
public class StudentSyncer : ISyncer
{
    // simple XML reader, reads XML file into a list of List<XMLStudent>
    private XMLStudentReader _reader;

    public StudentSyncer(string file)
    {
        _reader = new XMLStudentReader(file);
    }

    public string Sync()
    {
        // read the input
        List<XMLStudent> source = _reader.ReadAll();

        // using automapper map to domain object
        List<Student> dbStudent = Mapper.Map<List<XMLStudent>, List<Student>>(source);
        dbStudent.ForEach(s => s.IsCurrent = true);                // set IsCurrent

        // write records to Student table, using Unit of Work patterns
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(context);

            // set the existing records to not current
            var curSet = uow.Student.FindByTrackingChanges(s => s.IsCurrent == true).ToList();
            curSet.ForEach(s => s.IsCurrent = false);
            uow.Student.AddRange(dbStudent);
            uow.SaveChanges();
        }

        return "";  // no error
    }
}
```

I have a Windows service, which calls the `DoSync()` method every 30 seconds:

```
public void DoSync()
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Source", "*.xml"))
    {
        // use syncer factory to initialize the correct instance of syncer based on input file name
        ISyncer syncer = _syncerFactory.CreateInstance(file);

        // do the synchronization task
        syncer.Sync();

        // Move file to processed folder
        MoveFile(@"C:\Destination");
    }
}
```

The Factory is a simple factory. It reads the source file name, e.g. Student.XML, School.XML and based on the file name. It initializes the correct Syncer, e.g. `StudentSyncer`, `SchoolSyncer`.

I am happy with the code, but it is bothering me because I feel it is not following the Single Responsibility Principle. My `Syncer` class is not doing 1 task, but it is doing 3 tasks: read input, map to domain class, write to DB.

Comment: _Synchronizer should watch the Source folder_ - where is the code that does that? Have you removed anything?

Comment: @t3chb0t, thanks. It's a Windows event handler which calls DoSync () every 30 seconds. I did not include that part of the code in the review as I thought it's straight forward ... can add it, if it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late, but instead of the timed call to `DoSync()`, you could consider to use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) and then subscribe to the relevant events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that's an alternative and @t3chb0t gave the same comment... my main question is about Single Responsibility Principle... at what point do we say that a class has too many responsibilities and we should refactor it? The best article that I have seen is [this one by Nikola Malovic](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/)... I think Nikola's 2nd law of Ioc answers my question above: "Any class having more then 3 dependencies should be questioned for SRP violation"

Comment: @HoomanBahreini: OK, I haven't seen that comment. About SRP: This can be obtained on all levels of a project (modules, classes, methods) and depends on the abstraction level IMO: On one level of abstraction your `Syncer` does only one thing (syncronize a db from a xml file) but on another it does three: read, map, save - and one an even lower level the reading is about reading each byte from a stream etc.... In each project you have to find a reasonable ratio between SRP and fragmentation. I agree that you question may be more about IoC than SRP.

Answer (score 0):

How about extracting tasks common to all source types into an (abstract) base class that, in turn, implements your ISyncer interface?

I would also change the error reporting by using exceptions, rather than have the method return a string in case of error.

Edit, code example (C#-ish pseudo code)

```
abstract class SyncerBase : ISyncer
{
    sealed List<T> Map(List source, List target)
    {
        // Mapping magic here
    }

    sealed SaveToDB(List dataToSave, params ...)
    {
        // Your database access here
    }
}
```

Put utility methods and common stuff for all your synchronizers in that base class, and inherit it.

```
class StundentSyncer : SyncerBase
{
    // Constructor as in your code
    void Sync(string file)
    {
        var XMLstudents = _reader.ReadAll();
        var students = Map(XMLstudents); // calling base class here!
        // Manipulate student list here as needed
       SaveToDB (students, database params here) // base class here, too
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Exception is very good advice. I am not sure what you mean about abstracting the common functinality of all types?

Comment: @Hooman you mention that you have _StudentSyncer, SchoolSyncer, etc_ - it's very likely that they repeat the same code but it's hard to say because we don't see the other implemenations.

Comment: What is type T? And how to initialize Syncer / SyncerBase using a factory pattern? The reason I did not include Reader, Writer and Mapper inside ISyncer, was that I wanted to easily initialize the Syncers in a Factory.